# Hardware key combinations to enable/disable TalkBack

Tags: hardware, accessibility, talk-back

I have found the following gestures out options I the TalkBack settings:

[image: TalkBack settings]

I want to be able to get the double Coyle up and volume down long press key combination to toggle TalkBack on or off.

This is very useful.

(but it is grayed out)

Hopefully using it won't trigger the volume change if the user is clumsy and asynchronous presses both keys.

Thanks.